# BeginTransaction on localdb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb

I have an connection to LocalDB database:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mysite-20160510105433.mdf
```

I used code first with Entity Framework and the following piece of code:

```
var tran = this.context.Database.BeginTransaction();
//some operations on dbcontext
tran.Rollback();
```

where `context` variable is simple `DbContext` instance.

THe exception "The underlying provider failed on rollback" is thrown. 
Such an exception is **not thrown when** using normal, SQL Server connection.

Does it mean that localdb doesn't support transaction? If yes, how to achieve it?

**Or does it come from that connections run per process, so when query is over then connection is closed automatically?**

Edit: sample operations that I perform:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntityA();
this.context.MyEntitiesA.Add(myEnttiy).
this.context.Save(); //save to retreive id

// some playing with id

var mySecondEntity= new MyEntityB(){ MyEntityAId = myEntityA.Id, //other data gethered in "playing part" } ;
this.context.MyEntitiiesB.Add(mySecondEntity).
this.context.Save(); //need to rollback first, when here fails.
```

So I want to enclose within transaction:

```
using (var tran = this.context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // operations
        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
       // stuff
       tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

So as you can see transaction is useful here.

Comment: Seems you are using Entity Framework. EF will automatically enclose the any calls to Save and SaveAsync in a database transaction and roll back the transaction if there is a failure. An explicit call to tran.Rollback should not be required. If I am not understanding why you are calling it explicitly please provide additional code where you are manipulating the database before you are calling the rollback.

Comment: Do you get any more details (eg an inner exception) when this error occurs?

Comment: @Igor- you are wrong. Save or SaveAsync do not close connection. automaticaly - please reffer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx. You can see, that transaction can be commit/rollback after Save / SaveAsync - that is purpose of transactions. Why I need it is not revelant here. The thing it is that code works perfectly in SQL Server Instance, but not in Localdb.

Comment: @sgmoore Yes, I got argument null exception - connection parameter as InnerException

Comment: Issuing a `.Rollback()` call in response to an exception is incorrect. If the exception is the result of the transaction failing, it will have already rolled back. The correct pattern is `using (var transaction = ...) { ... transaction.Commit(); }`. Any transaction disposed without a `.Commit()` occurring (which is what happens on an unhandled exception) will implicitly rollback.

Comment: @JeroenMostert tried that - the same problem.